# Event Handling in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to use VB .NET 4.0 event handling to loosen up object dependancies in my project.
I've compiled the following (simple) example code which illustrates the nature of my problem:

Example form (which should catch the raised event):

```
Public Class Form1

Dim WithEvents obj1 As Class1
Dim WithEvents obj2 As Class2

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    obj1 = New Class1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    obj1.sendEvent()
End Sub

Public Sub handleEventFromClass2(ByRef sender As Class2, _ 
    ByVal op As Integer) Handles obj2.TestEvent
    TextBox1.Text = "Wert : " & op
End Sub
End Class
```

Content of example Class1 (just a class in the middle):

```
Public Class Class1

Public Sub sendEvent()
    Dim c2 As New Class2
    c2.sendEvent()
End Sub

End Class
```

Content of example Class2 (which defines and raises the event):

```
Public Shared Event TestEvent(ByRef sender As Class2, _
    ByVal testInteger As Integer)

Public Sub sendEvent()
    RaiseEvent TestEvent(Me, 4)
End Sub

End Class
```

I was expecting that the event is handled in Form1 - which isn't the case. Is there any way sending events "across" objects that are not "aware" of each other?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit sad that the compiler doesn't generate an error for this.  You have to make it look like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    obj1 = New Class1
    AddHandler Class2.TestEvent, AddressOf handleEventFromClass2
End Sub

Private Sub handleEventFromClass2(ByRef sender As Class2, _
    ByVal op As Integer)
    TextBox1.Text = "Wert : " & op
End Sub
```

Note that missing *Handles* keyword on the event handler and the explicit use of the AddHandler keyword.  You are however going to get yourself into trouble with these Shared events.  There is no mechanism that automatically unsubscribes the event, *Shared* makes it global so it lives for the duration of your program.  Even after the user has closed the form.  That's going to go bad, an ObjectDisposedException is likely be raised when you fire the event since the form object is dead.  Furthermore, you have a permanent leak since the form object can't be garbage collected.

You have to explicitly unsubscribe the event:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    RemoveHandler Class2.TestEvent, AddressOf handleEventFromClass2
End Sub
```

Event sources that outlive their listeners are troublesome.  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424516/unsubscribing-forms-components-from-long-lived-event-sources-when/3424920#3424920) for a completely different approach.

Comment: Hi Hans! Thanks a lot for this perfect explanation! My initial intention was to use Events for implementing loose coupling between code parts. The use of shared events was more an act of desperation :-). Good to know that this is at least a possible option. After some consideration, I'm going back to the classic approach by adding an interface instead of using events. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have two different instances of `Class2`.  You can make the constructor for `Class1` take your form's instance of `Class2` as a parameter.

Comment: Thx Tim, is there any way in avoiding this coupling between the Form and Class2? More in a sense of a "system" event.